# scale and move GameObject hit by Raycast and reset to Original in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, interaction

I use Vuforia for my AR Setup in Unity. I put the script below on an empty GameObject (which is not a child of my imagetarget) and assiged the public values in the inspector. When an Imagetarget is found the GameObjects appear. Then i select the objects via **Raycast**(AR camera). The problems occur when it comes to **scaling and moving** the GameObject.

I am not able to set the value back to the default transforms. I made a workaround for the localScale and position where i put some values as "limits". But this is acually not what i wanted to achieve. The position is behaving really weird.  The only thing i want to achieve is Hit the object - scale it by a value and move the object towards y - when not hit, the object should simply reset to its original values. It would be great if someone could help me to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance, milla

I am testing with Unity3d 2021.3.9f and Vuforia 10.14.4.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScaleOnHit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera arCamera; // Reference to the AR camera in the scene

    [SerializeField] private string selectableTag = "Selectable";
   
    public Vector3 targetScale = new Vector3(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);
    public Vector3 defaultScale = new Vector3(0.008f, 0.008f, 0.008f);
    public float duration = 2.0f;
    public float moveY = 0.01f;
    public AnimationCurve curve;
    private Transform _selection;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (_selection != null)
        {
            for (float time = 0; time < duration; time += Time.deltaTime)
            {
                // Calculate the current scale based on the elapsed time and set it
                float t = time / duration;
                var easing = curve.Evaluate(t);
                _selection.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(targetScale, defaultScale, easing);
                
            }
            _selection = null;
        }
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(arCamera.transform.position, arCamera.transform.forward); // Create a ray from the AR camera position in the direction it's facing

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) // Check if the ray hits an object
        {
            GameObject store = hit.collider.gameObject;
        
            var selection = hit.transform;
        
            if (selection.CompareTag(selectableTag))
            {
                if (hit.transform.position.y < -1.0f || hit.transform.position.y > -0.5f)
                {
                    selection.position = new Vector3(
                       hit.transform.position.x,
                       hit.transform.position.y + moveY,
                       hit.transform.position.z);
                }
                for (float time = 0; time < duration; time += Time.deltaTime)
                {
                    float t = time / duration;
                    var easing = curve.Evaluate(t);
                    selection.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(defaultScale, targetScale, easing);  
                }
                
                _selection = selection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```